# Floyd's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

This I keep running but its not running correctly I am not getting the right answers

```java
  public static void Floyd(int n, int [][] W, int [][] D, int [][] P) 
    {

      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
      P[i][j]=0;
       D = W;
    for (int k = 0; k<=n; k++)
        for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++)
         for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
         {
                if (D[i][k] + D[k][j]< D[i][j])
                {
                    P[i][j] =k;
               D[i][j] = D[i][k]+D[k][j];

                }
            }



      } // end Floyd

    public static void printArray(int n, int [][] A) {
      int i, j;
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("       ");

      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         System.out.printf("%7d", i);
      System.out.println("\n");

      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         System.out.printf("%7d", i);
         for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            System.out.printf("%7d", A[i][j]);
         System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.println();
       } // end printArray
```

Here is my main which and the above are my print method and floyd methods... I think there is something wrong with the floyd method

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner input;

      String inputFileName;
      System.out.print("\nEnter input file name:  ");
      inputFileName = kbd.nextLine();
      FileReader f = new FileReader(inputFileName);
      input = new Scanner(f);

      int i, j, n;
      n = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println();

      int [][] W = new int[n+1][n+1];
      int [][] D = new int[n+1][n+1];
      int [][] P = new int[n+1][n+1];

      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
         for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            W[i][j] = input.nextInt();


      System.out.println("W is:  ");
      printArray(n, W);

      Floyd(n, W, D, P);

      System.out.println("D is:  ");
      printArray(n, D);

      System.out.println("P is:  ");
      printArray(n, P);
```

Here is the output i am getting The graphs are not filling the way that they are supposed too

W is:

```
         1      2      3      4      5

  1      0     10   9999     10     50
  2     90      0     30     20   9999
  3   9999   9999      0     40   9999
  4   9999   9999     20      0     30
  5     30   9999   9999     90      0
```

D is:

```
         1      2      3      4      5

  1      0      0      0      0      0
  2      0      0      0      0      0
  3      0      0      0      0      0
  4      0      0      0      0      0
  5      0      0      0      0      0
```

P is:

```
         1      2      3      4      5

  1      0      0      0      0      0
  2      0      0      0      0      0
  3      0      0      0      0      0
  4      0      0      0      0      0
  5      0      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: `k` and `i` should go from 1 not from `0` in the triple cycle

Comment: You question is all about just code, add some words to describe the problem and some sample input output that you are looking for.